# Как результат команды raise преобразовать в строку?

Tags: python, исключения

Есть код:

```
try:
   plint("something")
except Exception as e:
   raise(e)
```

Я хочу результат команды `raise` преобразовать в строку `str()`, но не как не получается.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

воспользуйтесь [traceback.format_exc()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc):

```
import traceback

try:
   plint("something")
except Exception as e:
   err_text = traceback.format_exc()
   raise(e)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое